# Laravel WebSocket Chat

Tags: laravel, shell, websocket

I wrote chat using Ratchet and Laravel and I have one problem. How can I run command "chat:serve" on Shared Hosting? In cPanel CRON job needs path to the file. Can I use CRON job to solve this problem or maybe there are other ways? If yes, how should look the file that run command "chat:serve"? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a Command from a boot method if you want. The code I found for your chat is here https://github.com/assertchris-tutorials/laravel-4-real-time-chat/blob/master/workbench/formativ/chat/src/Formativ/Chat/Command/Serve.php

If you create a `new Serve` and then `fire()`it should work, as the constructor seems to do the work already and fire handles the rest.

```
<?php

    namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    use Formativ\Chat\Command\Serve;

    class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */


        function boot() {
            $serve = new Serve();
            $serve->fire();
        }
}
```

Comment: I get:
FatalThrowableError in Command.php line 253:
Call to a member function getOption() on null

Comment: Maybe it was because of my typo. see the current answer please, where I replaced `Serve->fire()`; with `$serve->fire();`

Comment: I noticed it earlier. I think that $this returns an error in the fire() method if it is called by boot().

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you any further for now: good luck though

Comment: I correctly call the fire() method but the website is constantly loading. Is it a server fault or it does not matter?